# Pytest assert syntax and how to call yml file from pytest function

Tags: python, yaml, pytest, assert

This is how I code my unit test:

```
def test_valid_number():
  check = requests.get("http://testing/validateNumber/021844223")
  assert True

def test_invalid_number():
  check = requests.get("http://testing/validateNumber/02188441")
  assert False
```

My questions are:

1. How to do assert (with pytest) correctly to check an API response? 
   The first function is to check valid number and it returns result:

   ```
   {"header":[{"STUDENTNUM":"P56219","STUDENTNAME":"GOLDIE",..... }
   ```

The second function is to check invalid number with the expected return:

```
    {"header":[],"headercount":0,"offers":[]}
```

2. Instead of coding the url and the student number manually. How can I create this in YAML and how to call the YAML file in my both functions.

Comment: https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/monkeypatch.html ?

Comment: 1. `check.json()` will give you a dictionary parsed from the response body, simply compare it against the expected one. 2. Either monkeypatch `requests.get` yourself, or use a third-party lib for that, such as [`requests-mock`](https://requests-mock.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

Comment: Please explain, by editing/updating your question (and without inserting **EDIT:** or something like that, keep it a single coherent whole), what you mean by by "calling a YAML file", AFAIK there is no such thing. E.g. do you mean loading the URL and the values to check against **from** a YAML file.

Comment: "you mean by by "calling a YAML file", AFAIK there is no such thing. E.g. do you mean loading the URL and the values to check against from a YAML file." --> yup that's what I had in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pytest provides a fixture `monkeypatch` and you can make use of it

```
def test_valid_number(monkeypatch):
    def patched_get():
        return {"header":[{"STUDENTNUM":"P56219","STUDENTNAME":"GOLDIE"}
    monkeypatch.setattr(requests, 'get', patched_get)
    assert check == {"header":[{"STUDENTNUM":"P56219","STUDENTNAME":"GOLDIE"}
```

To read YAML files, you need [PyYAML](https://pyyaml.org/). Install it with `pip`.

```
import yaml

with open("example.yml", "r") as f:
    test_data = yaml.load(f)

def test_valid_number():
    response = requests.get(test_data['url']).json()
    assert response == test_data['expected']
```

And the YAML file would look like this:

```
url: "http://testing/validateNumber/021844223"
expected:
  header:
    -
      STUDENTNUM: "P56219"
      STUDENTNAME: "GOLDIE"
      ......
```

Comment: The idea is not to hard code the response. For example, the STUDENTNUM value might change, depends on the student number I enter (in yaml). As long the header has values, I can assume the student number I put is a valid student number.

Comment: @Grandad36 I've provided an insight to do this and I think you can easily modify the above code to load a YAML file, no?

Comment: my limitation in programming (never create a yaml file before and don't know how to load the yaml config file from python file) holding me back from progressing forward :)

Comment: @Grandad36 OK, I got time to expand my answer. See the update.

Comment: thanks so much for your time to help a newbie like me. Now I can move forward with my codes!!!